# Al llamar un Datepicker con fecha de hoy o fecha default

Tags: android, date, datetime, datepicker

Tengo un textview que al presionarlo despliega un Datepicker pero este muestra por default la fecha de 01/01/1900, quiero que sea fecha de hoy al abrirlo o mínimo 01/01/1990 (preferencia).

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v==cliente_nacimiento){
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        dia=c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        mes=c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        año=c.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                    cliente_nacimiento.setText(dayOfMonth+"/"+(month+1)+"/"+year);
                }
            }
            ,dia,mes,año);
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error está en el que al setear las variables de `dia`, `mes` y `año` en el Datepicker están en el orden equivocado se debe setear en el siguiente orden `año`, `mes`, `dia`.

El código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```java
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == cliente_nacimiento) {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        dia = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        mes = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        anio = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                    cliente_nacimiento.setText(dayOfMonth+"/"+(month+1)+"/"+year);
                }
            }
            , anio, mes, dia);
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
    }
}
```

código completo: [GitHub](https://github.com/israteneda/StackOverflow/tree/master/DatePicker)